# Rubles — Russian and otherwise

Tags: discussion, tags

At the moment, Money SE has tag [rub-ruble](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rub-ruble) without synonyms and with the following description:

> This tag is to be used for the Ruble currency as used by Russia, Belarus, and the state of Transnistrian.

However, **RUB** is the [ISO 4217](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) code for the [Russian ruble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_ruble), not for the [Belarusian ruble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belarusian_ruble) (**BYN**). Hence, the tag name and its description do **not** match. Lastly, "Transnistria", not "Transnistrian".

Comment: Is there any controversy or can you just propose an update via the "Improve tag info" link? Others will have to review it.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica I could, indeed. But I don't know what the conventions are in Money SE.

Comment: Just go for it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Every one of the seven questions that uses this tag is about Russia. I propose changing the description to be only about the Russian Ruble. The currency from the three countries listed have nothing in common except that they happen to use the same name. It would be like lumping the U.S. and Canadian currencies into one tag.

Comment: There are non-EU countries that use EUR. There are EU countries that do not use EUR.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo You make an excellent point, and there are countries that use the US Dollar besides the USA. I don’t think the currency tags are very useful, but perhaps it doesn’t make sense to eliminate them altogether. I will edit my answer to remove that proposal.

Comment: I would keep the currency tags. One can be in country X and have savings in the currency of country Y. In this case, one would be subject to X's laws and to Y's central bank's policies.